# Enter key event to Street fighter 4 game through python

Tags: python, windows, events, keyboard

I have followed below given post to deal with key events.

[How can I send keyboard commands (hold,release,simultanous) with a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289777/how-can-i-send-keyboard-commands-hold-release-simultanous-with-a-python-script)

I am successfully able to send key events to all the windows executable programs except games. My need is, I have to press enter key when Street Fighter 4 game is launched at menu item. Basically I am trying to automate it.

When I followed, above given post, none of the keys are processed by the game.

Is there any reason behind it ? May be games don't allow programmatic key events ? I am not too sure 
it is just a wild guess, I am aware that even the keyboard events are also programatic key events.

I am using python language to process these events.

Comment: care to share the keystroke events you're sending the game?