# Python virtual keyboard -- issue with triple-key expression Ctrl-Shift-Home

Tags: python

I have been using a virtual keyboard that uses `ctypes` in Python 3.3 for a while, and I can't get it to do Ctrl-Shift-Home, among other triple-key expressions, like Ctrl-Alt-Delete. The expression Ctrl-Shift-Home selects the text starting at the cursor going back to the beginning of the text---which works when I press the expression manually, but I cannot get my code to do it.

My code is essentially the same as [the code from this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289777/how-can-i-send-keyboard-commands-hold-release-simultanous-with-a-python-script), and then to do the expression I could do something like

```
def Ctrl_Shift_Home():
    PressKey(0x11) # Ctrl
    PressKey(0x10) # Shift
    PressKey(0x24) # Home
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ReleaseKey(0x24)
    ReleaseKey(0x10)
    ReleaseKey(0x11)
```

But the above does not select any text. Is this an issue with the code itself, or an issue with triple-key expressions, or is selecting text just not allowed using keyboard events?

Any answers or alternatives would be appreciated! Thank you!